# Apache's reverse proxy stumping me with redirects

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, redirect, reverse-proxy

I have setting up a series of web apps, which for security purposes are only directly accessible via localhost, with each service attached to a different port. To make these apps externally accessible, a reverse proxy is being setup through apache. It has been running smoothly until adding another app today, which is forwarding after initial access (I don't know by what method though, I do not have access to the code that is doing the redirecting) in a way such that "proxyHost/bar/" is redirecting to "proxyHost/search/" instead of "proxyHost/bar/search/"

I have looked over my script for setting up the proxy multiple times and have tried different approaches I have read about online and none are working for me. I now  turn to you guys for help, I am very sorry if this is a rudimentary question or there is an obviously flaw in my config. I am quite new to apache.

Thanks!

Here is the current config:

```
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyHTMLEnable On

 <Proxy *>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 ProxyPass /foo/ http://localhost:1234/
 ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:1234 /foo

 <Location /foo/>
   ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:1234/
   ProxyHTMLURLMap /          /foo/
   ProxyHTMLURLMap /foo      /foo
 </Location>

 ProxyPass /bar/ http://localhost:5678/search
 ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:5678/ /bar

 <Location /bar/>
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5678/
   ProxyHTMLURLMap /            /bar/
   ProxyHTMLURLMap /bar     /bar
 </Location>
```

Answer (score 2):

To restate your problem:

You've installed a new "backend" application and made it accessible under `/bar` on your frontend host.  Access to the application results in a redirect to `/search` rather than `/bar/search`.

This generally happens because the backend application doesn't know anything about the frontend path under which you access it, and it generates absolute (vs. relative) URLs.  There are a few ways of solving this problem:

- Some applications let you configure a base URL that they will use when generating absolute links.  This is the easiest solution if it's available; you would set the base URL to `http://frontendhost/bar`.
- If you are unable to configure or modify the application, then you're going to need to filter the HTML it generates to rewrite links.  This is (explicitly) what [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) is for.  Note that for Apache 2.4 and great, `mod_proxy_html` is [included][] as a standard module; for earlier versions of Apache you'll need to install it separately.

The `mod_proxy_html` [documentation](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies) has some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
ProxyPassReverse /bar/ http://backend.example.com/search/
```

as [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) is what does the header rewrites and your new app is slighty different on the backend as it's hosted under /search and not / like your previous setup

*edit Sorry I haven't used mod_proxy_html before but the same goes for your ProxyHTMLURLMap directives. The need to map from /search to /bar as well.